# Python realtime timer

Tags: python, timer, counter

Could anybody advise me on converting the Java `Timer` class to Python? Currently I am converting a Java program to a Python script. However, Python does not have the Timer/TimerTask library (if it does have this, please enlighten me. Thanks!). I need to be able to reset the Timer. Java has `Timer.cancel`, but Python doesn't have this. Is there any replacement for it?

```
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
```

Java script timer

```
    class Timerclass extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;


    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times <= 5) {
             System.out.println(""+times);
        } else {
            this.cancel();
            //Stop Timer.
            System.out.println("Timer Finish");

        }

    }
}
```

Currently my code

```
import time
import threading

class Variable:
    count = 0
    people = 0
    times = 0

def enter():
    if int(Variable.count == 1):
        print("Entered")
        t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)
        t.start()
    else:
        print("Entered +1")
        t.clear() // Stuck Help 
        t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)
        t.start()
def out():
    if int(Variable.count > 0):
        print("Exited")
    elif int(Variable.count < 0):
        print("Error")

def countdown():
    print("TIMEUP")

while True:
    sensor1 = input("Sensor 1: ")
    sensor2 = input("Sensor 2: ")
    Variable.count+=1

    if int(sensor1) == int(sensor2):
        Variable.count -= 1
        print(Variable.count)
        print("error")
    elif int(sensor1) == 1:
        Variable.people += 1
        print(Variable.people)
        enter()
    elif int(sensor2) == 1:
        Variable.people -= 1
        print(Variable.people)
        out()
    else:
        print("Error")
```

i have one problems that i'm stuck in i need to stop the current counting and start a new one whenever the method call

Basically what i want or im looking out for is when i recall this method it will reset or cancel any existing and recount again

Update latest

```
import time
import threading

class Variable:
    count = 0
    people = 0
    times = 0

def countdown():
    print("TIMEUP")

t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)   
def enter():
    if int(Variable.count == 1):
        print("Entered")
        t.start()
    else:
        print("Entered +1")
        t.cancel()
        t.join()         # here you block the main thread until the timer is completely stopped
        t.start()

def out():
    if int(Variable.count > 0):
        print("Exited")
    elif int(Variable.count < 0):
        print("Error")

while True:
    sensor1 = input("Sensor 1: ")
    sensor2 = input("Sensor 2: ")
    Variable.count+=1

    if int(sensor1) == int(sensor2):
        Variable.count -= 1
        print(Variable.count)
        print("error")
    elif int(sensor1) == 1:
        Variable.people += 1
        print(Variable.people)
        enter()
    elif int(sensor2) == 1:
        Variable.people -= 1
        print(Variable.people)
        out()
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Anybody can spot my ,istake im getting this error but i t.clear() the process

in start raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Comment: Depending on how precise you need to be, you could get something working with the [```time``` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), but this is subject to system dependence (so its not always spot on)

Comment: @wnnmaw erm is just a counter which count 1,2,3,4,5,6 when it exceeds the value it will do something . when the function is recalled it will reset the counting again

Comment: Yeah, that's what a counter is.... You can still do it with ```time```

Comment: @DanvinLeeQicheng I updated my answer with an answer to your most recent issue.

Comment: @dano Thanks for the answer but there is one more problem at my def out: i need to reset and call the timer again anyway to make the t global and accessible for all

Answer (score 1):

Python actually has a class for this, which includes a `cancel` method: [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects). It seems to be close enough to the Java `Timer` class for your needs (The Java `Timer` also runs in background thread). Here's the example usage from the docs:

```
def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

**Edit:**

The problem with your updated code is that you're trying to use the same `Timer` object more than once. That may be possible in the Java implementation, but in Python you can't reuse a `Thread` object (`Timer` is a `Thread` subclass). You'll need to create a new Timer object after you join() it. Like this:

```
t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)   
def enter():
    global t  # You need this to tell Python that you're going to change the global t variable. If you don't do this, using 't = ..' will just create a local t variable.
    if int(Variable.count == 1):
        print("Entered")
        t.start()
    else:
        print("Entered +1")
        t.cancel()
        t.join()         # here you block the main thread until the timer is completely stopped
        t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [`time` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) for something like this:

```
from time import time, sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

nowtime = time()

#Put your script here
x = 1
for k in range(1000):
        x+=1
        sleep(0.01)

sec = timedelta(seconds=int(time()-nowtime))
d = datetime(1,1,1)+sec

print("DAYS:HOURS:MIN:SEC")
print("%d:%d:%d:%d" % (d.day-1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second))
```

This assigns the time in seconds at the beginning to a variable, and after the main script has finished, it subtracts the previous time from the current time and formats it in days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Here is it running:

```
bash-3.2$ python timing.py
DAYS:HOURS:MIN:SEC
0:0:0:10
bash-3.2$
```

You could also use the Threading module, which has a built-in cancel method:

```
>>> import threading
>>> def hello():
...     print "This will print after a desired period of time"
... 
>>> timer = threading.Timer(3.0, hello)
>>> timer.start() #After 3.0 seconds, "This will print after a desired period of time" will be printed
>>> This will print after a desired period of time

>>> timer.start()
>>> timer = threading.Timer(3.0, hello)
>>> timer.start()
>>> timer.cancel()
>>>
```

Comment: I don't know if I'd call editing your incorrect answer to include someone else's correct answer "how it's done", but to each his own, I guess.